# nextjs page not found after deployment

Tags: deployment, next.js, plesk, shared-hosting, file-not-found

I created a simple nextjs app using create-next-app
I added only some pages in pages folder (contact.js, help.js)

I can build and start app in localhost using below commands

```
npm run build
npm run start
```

this is script part of package.json

```
"scripts": {
"dev": "node server.js",
"build": "cross-env next build",
"start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node server.js",
"lint": "next lint"
```

},

I deployed this app on a shared host with plesk control panel
index page is ok,
but it not found help and contact pages
neither by typing url directly in address bar, nor clicking in Link (next/link)

.next folder content:

[image]

.next/server folder content:

[image]

.next/server/pages folder content:

[image]

at first I set Application Startup File to

```
node_modules/.bin/next
```

and tried run start script but it didn't work, so to start app
I set Application Startup File to: customserver.js in plesk like below:
[image]

[Custom Server](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server)

what can be wrong here?
any ideas?

Comment: Found any solution?